# Change business layer class to be loosely coupled

Tags: c#

I have below code I am working on. I am working on data access adon.net layer. I have problem with my business layer class called `UserBAL`. The problem is that I am creating instance of dal and dbmanager inside constructor of `UserBAL`. How can I change this to be loosely coupled for `UserBAL`? Hope you get my point.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int DoSomething(string one, int two);
}

public class User : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DoSomething(string one, int two)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserBal //busines logic
{
    private readonly IRepositoryDal<User> _userRepositoryDal;

    public UserBal()
    {
        _userRepositoryDal  = new UserRepositoryDal(new DbManager("sqlserver?"));
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> SearchByName(string name)
    {
        return _userRepositoryDal.SearchByName(name);
    }
}

interface IRepositoryDal<T> where T : IEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> SearchByName(string username);
    T SearchById(string id);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void Add(T entity);
}

public class UserRepositoryDal: IRepositoryDal<User>
{
    private readonly IDbManager _dbManager;

    public UserRepositoryDal(IDbManager dbManager)
    {
        //read from either singleton or configuration file !!
        _dbManager = dbManager;
    }
    public IEnumerable<User> SearchByName(string username)
    {                                  
            var parameters = new List<IDbDataParameter>
            {
                _dbManager.CreateParameter("@FirstName", 50, username, DbType.String),
            };

        var userDataTable = _dbManager.GetDataTable("storedpr2",
            CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters.ToArray());

        foreach (DataRow dr in userDataTable.Rows)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                Id = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()),
                Firstname = dr["Firstname"].ToString(),
                Lastname = dr["LastName"].ToString(),
                Email = dr["Email"].ToString()
            };

            yield return user;
        }

    }
    public User SearchById(string id)
    {
        var parameters = new List<IDbDataParameter>
        {
            _dbManager.CreateParameter("@Id", 50, id, DbType.Int32),
        };

        var userDataTable = _dbManager.GetDataTable("storedpr2",
            CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters.ToArray());

        return new User
        {
            Id = int.Parse(userDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString()),
            Firstname = userDataTable.Rows[0]["Firstname"].ToString(),
            Lastname = userDataTable.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString(),
            Email = userDataTable.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString()
        };
    }

    public void Update(User entity)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Remove(User entity)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(User entity)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public partial class FrmLogin : Form
{
    private readonly UserBal _userBal;

    public FrmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         _userBal = new UserBal();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for dependency injection here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [dependency injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/dependency-injection-is-passing-an-argument/), and for required dependencies, you can use constructor injection, e.g:

```
public class UserBal
{
    private readonly IRepositoryDal<User> _userRepositoryDal;

    public UserBal(IRepositoryDal<User> userRepositoryDal)
    {
        _userRepositoryDal = userRepositoryDal 
          ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepositoryDal));
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You pass an instance when constructing `UserBal`, i.e. `new UserBal(new UserRepositoryDal(new DbManager("sqlserver?"))`. You could also consider using an IoC container to manage these dependencies such as Autofac -https://autofac.org/.

Comment: @JimmyJimm  And then you have to set up Autofac and integrate it with your app.

Comment: not sure but then problem is with that: "new UserBal(new UserRepositoryDal(new DbManager("sqlserver?"))" because first from presentation layer i am passing new UserRepositoryDal. Shouldn't presentation layer doesn't know about this object? Also DbManager is passed from presentation layer. To my knowledge only UserBal should be known from that point.

Comment: You continue the pattern, so the presentation layer has a `UserBal` injected, therefore it doesn't need to know anything about how it's constructed. All of the wire up then happens in your application's composition root - http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/. I suggest you read Dependency Injection in .NET - https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition.

Comment: @devdigital can you explain as i don;t get. I still have to from presentation layer call it like this or not?: new UserBal(new UserRepositoryDal(new DbManager("sqlserver?"))

Comment: Yes that's correct, so for example a web application would have dependencies injected into your controller. This then requires IoC container integration so that instances of your controllers can be resolved via the container. There are examples of integrations on the Autofac site.

Comment: @devdigital and thats what i dont get, if i still have to pass dal and dbmanager object to uderbal ctor from presentation layer to me it has no sense because presentatoion layer knows about object it should doesn't know.

Comment: As I say, you don't construct the `UserBal` type from the presentation layer, you inject it into your controller constructor (assuming web application), the IoC container integrates with the appropriate pipeline which constructs controllers, and resolves instances of your services from the container.

Comment: I also don't recommend Enigmativity's approach, as all of your types require knowledge of the dependency injection approach. The only IoC container aware code should be your composition root - http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173059/discussion-between-jimmyjimm-and-devdigital).

Comment: @devdigital you mean from presentatin layer i just call it like: "new UserBal() without specyfing parameters which will be known somehow by IoC? P.S It's Windows Forms app.

Comment: No, you don't `new` up types, that is left to the IoC container. However, dependency injection with WinForms is trickier, as older frameworks are less dependency injection friendly, so you will need to research around this, or consider newer frameworks. However, I think the original question has been answered - dependency injection is the most common way to satisfy the Dependency Inversion Principle,  removing the coupling between types.

Comment: @devdigital can you update your answer to show how to call UserBal from presentationlayer (GUI) and how this IoC resolve it. I would appreciate to get full view.

Comment: I suggest you read some IoC container documentation - for example http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windowsformsintegration.html

Comment: @devdigital ok i will however i still not udnerstand why in presentation layer mentioned objects has to be shown, to me it's still break of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is the way to go. Here's a simplified example of your situation.

Given your classes could be like this:

```
public interface IEntity { }
public interface IRepositoryDal<T> where T : IEntity { }
public interface IDbManager { }

public class User : IEntity { }

public class UserBal //busines logic
{
    [Injectivity.Attributes.Inject]
    private IRepositoryDal<User> _userRepositoryDal;
}

public class UserRepositoryDal: IRepositoryDal<User>
{
    [Injectivity.Attributes.Inject]
    private IDbManager _dbManager;
}

public class DbManager : IDbManager
{
    [Injectivity.Attributes.Construct()]
    public DbManager([Injectivity.Attributes.Key("dbKey", typeof(string))] string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"DbManager created with parameter \"{x}\"");
    }
}
```

...then this code:

```
var context = Injectivity.Context.CreateRoot();

context.SetConfig<string>("dbKey", "sqlserver?");
context.SetFactory<IDbManager, DbManager>();
context.SetFactory<IRepositoryDal<User>, UserRepositoryDal>();
context.SetFactory<UserBal, UserBal>();

var user = context.Resolve<UserBal>();
```

...will produce this output:

```
DbManager created with parameter "sqlserver?"
```

Now, I've used a DI container that I wrote a number of years back. It's very flexible.

So the call to `context.Resolve<UserBal>();` runs down the chain of seeing what needs to be injected to create all of the instances of all of the objects. Ultimately the creation of `UserBal` requires the `DbManager` to be created and hence the output.

You would normally not explicitly register each factory. Normally you would put attributes on all of the classes you want to register and then use `context.Register(Assembly.LoadFrom("My.DLL"));` or create an XML config file and call `context.LoadConfig(XDocument.Load("config.xml"));`.

You can even do things like this:

```
context.SetDecorator<IRepositoryDal<User>, UserRepositoryDalDecorator>();
```

This will cause all calls to `context.Resolve<IRepositoryDal<User>>()` or `[Inject]` attributes to automatically wrap the real instances in this decorator. Ideal to intercepting method calls for debugging purposes.

Comment: Would it be possible to change that without attributes? For instance IoC container instead?

Comment: @JimmyJimm - This is an example of an IoC container. It just happens to use attributes to make registration easy. I did set it up to allow registrations via code (as also shown in my question). It only matter as to how registration of your classes needs to work. Attributes make it easy for you to register entire assemblies and thus swap in or out assemblies at run-time.